# Bash: Control argument grouping in shell variables?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, grouping, argument-passing

I have a program that accepts an argument of the style `-g "hello world"`.

For the program to work correctly, `-g` and `"hello world"` actually have to be two separate arguments.

The shell script below is thought to automate something:

```
MYPROG=/path/to/bin
MYARG=-g\ \"hello\ world\"

"$MYPROG" "$MYARG"
```

Of course, this doesn't work because `-g "hello world"`is treated as a single argument by bash.

One solution would be to split `-g` and `"hello world"` directly in the shell script to have something like:

```
MYPROG=/path/to/bin
MYARG1=-g
MYARG2=\"hello\ world\"

"$MYPROG" "$MYARG1" "$MYARG2"
```

This would work because now the two arguments are treated as such.
However, because `-g` and `"hello world"` belong together, the shell script would look kind of awkward. Especially if there are hundreds of arguments defined like this in the script.

Now my question is, how can I get my shell script to treat the one variable as two arguments without splitting them into two variables?

Comment: The only sensible way to deal with this (in Bash) is to use an array.

Comment: @shellter I already tried that, unfortunately it doesn't group my args at a whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @gniourf_gniourf said, the best way to handle this is with an array:

```
MYPROG=/path/to/bin
MYARGS=(-g "hello world")

"$MYPROG" "${MYARGS[@]}"
```

The assignment statement defines MYARGS as an array with two elements: "-g" and "hello world". The `"${arrayname[@]"` idiom tells the shell to treat each element of the array as a separate argument, without word-splitting or otherwise mangling them.

Comment: Thank you both, this does what I want without unnecessarily complicating my shell script!